# My Arcmap 10.3 icon missing

Tags: esri, arcmap

My Arcmap 10.3 does not have an icon on my desktop - I can't find how to add a shortcut to my bar and so I have to open older MXD files to get to the program.

I have already tried finding it in the program files and there is no icon for the program anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find `ArcMap.exe` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\bin` directory.

Once there, right-click and select "Send To -> Desktop (create shortcut)", "Pin to Taskbar", and/or "Pin to Start Menu".

Answer (score 1):

you could use the solution of Erica or you could go on start and write arcmap and you click on it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please search in the search bar "ArcMap"
[image]